# $resource function wrapper angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently, I'm doing things like this:

```
var albumList = $resource('https://api.imgur.com/3/account/guy123/albums').get(function () {
    albumList.data.forEach(function (album) {
        albums.push(album);
    });
});
```

How do I turn that into a function that I can call in both my service and controller like:

```
factory('Imgur', function($resource, $http) {
    var albumsService = {};
    var albums = [];

    albumsService.getAlbumList = function() {
        var albumList = $resource('https://api.imgur.com/3/account/guy123/albums').get(function () {
            albumList.data.forEach(function (album) {
                albums.push(album);
            });
        });
    };

    albumsService.albumList = function() {
        albumsService.getAlbumList();
        return albums;
    };

    return albumsService;
});


.controller('Filters', ['$scope','Imgur', function($scope, Imgur) {
    $scope.imgur = Imgur;
    $scope.imgur.albumList();
    //OR
    $scope.imgur.getAlbumList();

    //Some good context here is what if a user wanted to "refresh" the data.
    $scope.updateFilter = function() {
        $scope.imgur.getAlbumList();
    }; 


}]);
```

*Ultimately the goal here is to be able to call a resource service as many times as I want. The service should be a function callable by both inside the service and inside the controller.*

Comment: Might help to see a plunkr/fiddle of the entire code/controller etc.

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. I think you're overcomplicating things.  Are you just trying to access the imgur api, but have the results in a different format? It's unclear what your problem is.

Comment: The 2nd to last line `$scope.imgur.albumList();` doesn't make sense. You're not assigning the result of the function to anything.

Comment: @jessegavin Yea sorry syntax from copying. So, I am trying to wrap `var albumList` as a function. Ultimately the goal here is to be able to call a resource service as many times as I want. The service should be a function callable by both inside the service and inside the controller.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Are you attempting to display any of the data from Imgur? If so, you'll need to assign the results from your service function to a property on the scope.

Comment: @DanKanze, I am also confused, why would you need or want to call the service more than once, after you have the objects all manipulation/filtering can be managed within angular, without the need to make additional calls.   What reason would another call be made?

Comment: @zmanc Yea I am thinking what if I need to update the result set. I also have functions I need to run on the data once it comes back so I dont want to return it right away.

Comment: In the example I gave you can just call the albumsService.query() to update the result set.  The use case I have is that I add a new entry, after the save of the entry I call my version of albumsService.query() and that will update the results on the page.   Also if you need to modify the data or run functions on it before it is displayed you can do that before you assign it to the $scope.albumList.

Comment: @zmanc But if the same functions are run on the data every time, dont they belong in the service?

Comment: if the same functions are run every time do you have a way to perform them on the server instead of on the client?  Personally I prefer to perform manipulation at the controller level if I do not want to do it on the server side.

Comment: @zmanc Wish I could, not my API ^_-

Comment: Since it is not your api then you can just modify the data in the controller before you assign it to the albumList.

Comment: @zmanc That seems really dirty if muitliple controllers are using the same data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29502/discussion-between-zmanc-and-dan-kanze)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module("MyApp", ['ng-resource']).
  service("Database", function() {
    return {
      albums : $resource('https://api.imgur.com/3/account/guy123/albums')
    }
  }).
  controller("MyCtrl", function(Database) {
    $scope.albums = Database.albums.query();
  })
```

Then in your Html

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head></head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="album in albums">
      {{album.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I would need to be able to make service calls within the service itself, thus the need to execute the service as a function.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: I made some edits to post hopefully that will clear up confusion.

Comment: Ok it seems like what I am trying to do isn't going to work out. I need to rethink my app structure. However, using this method, how do I impliment success and error handlers in both the controller? In other words - assign `$scope.albums` = `data` on success.

Answer (score 1):

The Service

```
var service = angular.module("yourApp.service", ['ngResource']);
service.factory('albumsService', [$resource',function ($resource){
    return $resource('https://api.imgur.com/3/account/guy123/albums',{},{
         query: {method: "GET", isArray:true}
    });
}]);
```

Then in the controller

```
$scope.albumList = albumsService.query();
```

Comment: I would need to be able to make service calls within the service itself, thus the need to execute the service as a function.

Comment: Could you possibly use  params: ?  Depending on what type of service calls you are doing.  I know in one of my use cases I have several types of requests that I manage through parameters.

Comment: I made some edits to post hopefully that will clear up confusion.

Comment: Ok it seems like what I am trying to do isn't going to work out. I need to rethink my app structure. However, using this method, how do I impliment success and error handlers in both the controller? In other words - assign `$scope.albumList` = `data` on success.

Comment: As per the angular doc "Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering, once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the new data. This means that in most case one never has to write a callback function for the action methods."   http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource#Returns